# How can I upload directory to FTP?

Tags: java, android, file, ftp

This is my code:

```
public void UploadIt(){
    org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("ftp server");

        if (con.login("username", "pass"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = baseDir + "/emre";

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.storeFile("/", in);
            in.close();
            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(" dead","ddsd");
    }

}
```

I can upload file, but I can't upload directory.When I try upload dir or folder it says "... Is directory" and it doesn't upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upload the files recursively from the directory after creating directory on ftp as creation of folder and file creation on ftp cannot be done simultaneously they are separate commands.

```
public static void uploadDirectory(FTPClient ftpClient,
        String remoteDirPath, String localParentDir, String remoteParentDir)
        throws IOException {

    System.out.println("LISTING directory: " + localParentDir);

    File localDir = new File(localParentDir);
    File[] subFiles = localDir.listFiles();
    if (subFiles != null && subFiles.length > 0) {
        for (File item : subFiles) {
            String remoteFilePath = remoteDirPath + "/" + remoteParentDir
                    + "/" + item.getName();
            if (remoteParentDir.equals("")) {
                remoteFilePath = remoteDirPath + "/" + item.getName();
            }


            if (item.isFile()) {
                // upload the file
                String localFilePath = item.getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println("About to upload the file: " + localFilePath);
                boolean uploaded = uploadSingleFile(ftpClient,
                        localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
                if (uploaded) {
                    System.out.println("UPLOADED a file to: "
                            + remoteFilePath);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("COULD NOT upload the file: "
                            + localFilePath);
                }
            } else {
                // create directory on the server
                boolean created = ftpClient.makeDirectory(remoteFilePath);
                if (created) {
                    System.out.println("CREATED the directory: "
                            + remoteFilePath);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("COULD NOT create the directory: "
                            + remoteFilePath);
                }

                // upload the sub directory
                String parent = remoteParentDir + "/" + item.getName();
                if (remoteParentDir.equals("")) {
                    parent = item.getName();
                }

                localParentDir = item.getAbsolutePath();
                uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localParentDir,
                        parent);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static boolean uploadSingleFile(FTPClient ftpClient,
        String localFilePath, String remoteFilePath) throws IOException {
    File localFile = new File(localFilePath);

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    try {
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        return ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFilePath, inputStream);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

source: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/how-to-upload-a-directory-to-a-ftp-server

Comment: @emre3461 .. If you google about you will get lot of answers on this. I have updated the answer from one.